# Why Table of Contents contains custom latex command?

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

I am writing a UTF-8 (malayalam) document using Xelatex.

Below shown is my sample Latex code. If you see(screenshot) the Table Of Contents generated, you can see `Noto Sans Malayalam`  which came because I had to type my UTF-8 text using my custom made `\noto` command `\def\noto{\fontspec{Noto Sans Malayalam}}`
 .

Do you know how to remove this unwanted text `Noto Sans Malayalam` in my pdf's Table of Contents ?

[image]

```
% xelatex test.tex 

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\noto{\fontspec{Noto Sans Malayalam}}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents \\ {\noto ഉളളടക്കം }}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Malayalam  \\ \noto{ മലയാളം } }

Malayalam \\ {\noto മലയാളം}
\newpage

\section{English  \\ \noto{ ഇംഗ്ലീഷ് }            }

English \\ {\noto ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may be interested in a little macro called `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}`...

Comment: Use `\newcommand\noto{\texorpdfstring{\fontspec{Noto Sans Malayalam}}{}}`

Comment: Do you need the english and malayalam to be in different fonts? If not, why not just set the main font `\setmainfont`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.pdf` file can't interpret the `\noto` command and the font specification correctly for the `bookmarks`.

Use `\texorpdfstring{\fontspec{...}}{}`

I've removed the 'wrong' `\\` usages as well.

The Noto fonts can be downloaded from https://www.google.com/get/noto/

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\noto}{\texorpdfstring{\fontspec{Noto Sans Malayalam}}{}}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents \\ {\noto ഉളളടക്കം }}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Malayalam  \noto{ മലയാളം } }

Malayalam 

 {\noto മലയാളം}

\clearpage
\section{English   \noto{ ഇംഗ്ലീഷ് }            }

English 

{\noto ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it wrong to use "\\ " ? Or you meant I used at wrong place ?

Comment: @robomon:  leave an empty line rather in normal text if you want a linebreak. In the `\section` etc. headings, well, use `\\` rather then or `\\[1ex]`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have neither `\\` nor `\noto` in the bookmarks. The simplest solution is to use a command for the section titles:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily\noto{Malayalam MN} % I don't have Noto
\newcommand{\nototitle}[1]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\\{\noto #1}}{#1}%
}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents \\[1ex] {\noto ഉളളടക്കം}}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Malayalam\nototitle{മലയാളം}}

Malayalam \\ {\noto മലയാളം}
\newpage

\section{English\nototitle{ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്}}

English \\ {\noto ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\fontspec` in the body of the document; using `\newfontface` in the preamble once and for all is much more efficient.

[image]